# How to get original column name after a column is renamed using SharePoint Object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, splistitem

Currently i am working on a module to export a list item to PDF using itextsharp.dll, I am having issues reading values of the renamed columns.

**For example below column is renamed once i don't know its original column name.**
Intername is "Legal_x003A__x0020__x0020_Commen"  , and Display Name is "Legal: Comments Categories"

1)is there any method to get display name using Internal Name?

(Or)

2)is there any method to get the value of the column using Display Name? ( it says column does not exists may be deleted another user)

Note: I can use internal name to get column value but i don't want "Legal_x003A__x0020__x0020_Commen" in column name field.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgqst.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue,  You can get display name of the column using its Internal Column Name

```
SPField fDisplayname = SPContext.Current.Item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(InternalColumnName);
```